# Java inheritence and arraylist to sort

Tags: java

Hey i have a project in which by using inheritence and arraylist i have to take input from file and then show the output after sorting them year wise but in my code my array list's are empty and i am not able to figure out how to solve it.
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        driver.start();

    }

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.io.*;
public class Driver {
    
    public void start() throws FileNotFoundException{
        
        // Initialize arraylists
        ArrayList<Movie> adventure = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Movie> drama = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Movie> fantasy = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Movie> romance = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Movie> sciFi = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Movie> thriller = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Movie> war = new ArrayList<>();
        
        
            File myObj = new File("MovieListing.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            String directorName = myReader.nextLine();
            String composerName = myReader.nextLine();
            
            
            while(myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String movie = myReader.nextLine();
               String[] movieInfo = movie.split(",");
               String title = movieInfo[0];
               int year = Integer.parseInt(movieInfo[1]);
               String genre = movieInfo[2];
               String rating = movieInfo[3];
               
               Movie movie1 = new Movie(title,year,genre,rating,directorName,composerName);
               
            //sort movies into arraylists
                if (genre.equals("Adventure"))
                {
                   adventure.add(movie1);
                }
                else if (genre.equals("Drama"))
                {
                   drama.add(movie1);
                }
                else if (genre.equals("Fantasy"))
                {
                   fantasy.add(movie1);
                }
                else if (genre.equals("Romance"))
                {
                   romance.add(movie1);
                }
                else if (genre.equals("Sci Fi"))
                {
                   sciFi.add(movie1);
                }
                else if (genre.equals("Thriller"))
                {
                   thriller.add(movie1);
                }
                else if (genre.equals("War"))
                {
                   war.add(movie1);
                }
            }
            myReader.close();
        
            System.out.print(adventure);
             for(Movie movie:war) {
                System.out.print(movie.getTitle());
             }
        
        // Ask the user which genre they would like to view
        String genre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Director: " +directorName +  "\n" +
                "Composer: " + composerName + "\n" +
                "Which genre would you like? \n" +
                "1. Adventure \n" +
                "2. Drama \n" +
                "3. Fantasy \n" +
                "4. Romance \n" +
                "5. SciFi \n" +
                "6. Thriller \n" +
                "7. War \n" +
                "Your choice: ");

        // Sort the movies by year released
        adventure.sort(new MovieComparator());
        drama.sort(new MovieComparator());
        fantasy.sort(new MovieComparator());
        romance.sort(new MovieComparator());
        sciFi.sort(new MovieComparator());
        thriller.sort(new MovieComparator());
        war.sort(new MovieComparator());
        
       

        // Display the output dialog box
        String output = "Director: " +directorName + "\n" +
                "Composer: " +composerName + "\n" +
                "Genre: " + genre + "\n" +
                "Movie Title\tYear Released\tRating\n";
        if (genre.equals("1")) {
            for (Movie movie : adventure) {
                output += movie.getTitle() + "\t\t" + movie.getYearReleased() + "\t\t" + movie.getRating() + "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (genre.equals("2")) {
            for (Movie movie : drama) {
                output += movie.getTitle() + "\t\t" + movie.getYearReleased() + "\t\t" + movie.getRating() + "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (genre.equals("3")) {
            for (Movie movie : fantasy) {
                output += movie.getTitle() + "\t\t" + movie.getYearReleased() + "\t\t" + movie.getRating() + "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (genre.equals("4")) {
            for (Movie movie : romance) {
                output += movie.getTitle() + "\t\t" + movie.getYearReleased() + "\t\t" + movie.getRating() + "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (genre.equals("5")) {
            for (Movie movie : sciFi) {
                output += movie.getTitle() + "\t\t" + movie.getYearReleased() + "\t\t" + movie.getRating() + "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (genre.equals("6")) {
            for (Movie movie : thriller) {
                output += movie.getTitle() + "\t\t" + movie.getYearReleased() + "\t\t" + movie.getRating() + "\n";
            }
        }
        else if (genre.equals("7")) {
            for (Movie movie : war) {
                output += movie.getTitle() + "\t\t" + movie.getYearReleased() + "\t\t" + movie.getRating() + "\n";
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    }

}


public class Movie extends Director {
    
    private String title;
    private int yearReleased;
    private String genre;
    private String rating;



    public Movie(String title, int yearReleased, String genre, String rating, String directorName, String composerName) {
        
        super(directorName, composerName);
        this.title = title;
        this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.rating = rating;

    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public int getYearReleased() {
        return yearReleased;
    }
    public void setYearReleased(int yearReleased) {
        this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
    }
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
   

}


public class Director {
    
    private String directorName;
    private String composerName;
    
    public Director(String d, String c) {
        this.directorName = d;
        this.composerName = c;
    }

    
    public String getDirectorName() {
        return directorName;
    }

    public void setDirectorName(String directorName) {
        this.directorName = directorName;
    }

    public String getComposerName() {
        return composerName;
    }

    public void setComposerName(String composerName) {
        this.composerName = composerName;
    }
}
```

This is the link for the file that needs to be useed in the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FkDSAlEv3waby-ML1dKPf3Ouk3S7O99O/view?usp=sharing

```
Ecpected output format:-
Director:     Steven Spielberg
Composer: John Williams

Genre:  Drama

Movie Title   Year Released    Rating
Amistad               1997               R
The Post              2017               PG-13
```

....

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: I'am not able to figure out why my arraylist are empty because my variable are getting populated by the input file but they are not adding to the arraylist can you just help me out in that part

Comment: Your problem is due to a program that is not behaving as expected or desired, and if you don't know why this is occurring then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I don't know why your lists are empty, but you can answer that question by stepping through your program until you get to the `if` statements surrounding the `add`, and checking what value `genre` has at that point.

Comment: It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer. You should always do this *before* asking your question, and show the results of your debugging efforts in with your question.

Comment: Note also that your question's title is misleading.  The question that you asked is neither about inheritence (sic) or sorting.  It is actually about some bug in your code for reading / parsing / loading data from a file.

Comment: Which is exactly why you should debug before posting

Answer (score 1):

Running your code without any changes throwed an exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1994"

The exception was reported to be caused by this statement in class Driver:

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(movieInfo[1]);
```

The reason is quite obvious: There is a leading space infront of 1994, that's why it is throwing that exception. The reason why there is a space infront of 1994 lies within the input file:

```
Schindler's List, 1994, War, R
```

The same applies for the "genre" column in the input file and that's the reason why none of the imported movies is associated to the pre-defined genres during import:

```
if (genre.equals("War")) {
```

" War" (from import) is different from "War".

You need to remove leading (and trailing) spaces during import. You could do this calling [java.lang.String#trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) on item of array `movieInfo` or by using an appropriate regular expression whith [java.lang.String#split(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
String[] movieInfo = movie.split(",\\s*");
```

This will split the input line at every occurence of "comma, followed optionally by spaces", effectively removing leading spaces from the imported fields.